# Routing High Current Trace to 0.5mm Pitch QFN IC

Tags: pcb, motor, routing

I'm designing a PCB which uses TI's [DRV8411ARTER](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8411a.pdf?ts=1692669371223&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253DDRV8411ARTER%2526nr%253D2) 4 Half Bridge motor driver. However, I've run into a routing issue which I'm not sure what the best plan of action is.

[image]

The driver will be outputting around 1.8A for each of its two channels at max load. But it's such a fine pitch IC that I had to reduce the width of the high current trace before connecting to the IC. I was thinking of removing the solder mask on this trace to tin with some solder but I've never tried to tin a 0.3 mm wide trace before.

Is there any better method I can use to route these traces? I find it odd that they make an IC which is rated to 4 A so small that you can't easily route high current traces to and from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. 1.8A isn't very much.  0.5mm width traces will be more than enough (preferably 1oz+ copper PCB).  That said, you'll probably still need to neck down for the pad.
2. Trace width only matters over such lengths that no heat flows lengthwise along it, i.e. it's balanced, no temp drop along the trace, and heat flows laterally only, out to surroundings.  For typical copper on PCBs this is a length of ballpark, oh, 20+ trace widths say?

Trace width calculators assume this condition: that it's long enough to ignore end effects.

That doesn't mean trace width can be *ignored* for short distances, of course; it means that there are other factors.  If it's a thin section flanked by large sections, large heatsinks small, and it can take way more current (for a given temp rise).

Unrelated: you may want to disable thermal relief spokes on vias.  This will give better copper fill on the backside under the QFN.

Comment: Ok. The trace going to the IC is limited to 0.3mm becuase my minimum clearance is 0.2mm. Yea online calculators said I needed 0.5mm for 50 degree temperature rise with 1oz copper. So would you say there's no need to remove solder mask and tin traces? I was worried that the skinny 0.3mm section would burn out becuase of its higher resistance compared to the thicker trace and thus consume more power.

Comment: You might be looking at the internal traces from your PCB trace width calculator.  0.3mm wide 5mm long external traces on 1oz Cu with 1.8A each will give <40C rise which, unless you are inside a sauna, should be fine on FR4.  Like Tim said, it doesn't take into account heat dissipating into the larger trace so the real temp rise will probably be less.  It's also possible that heat could go into the package if the EP is well heatsinked.  Look at the "layout" section of the datasheet, the linked app note (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva959b/slva959b.pdf) and lose the spokes on the backside vias.

Comment: Indeed; and how much resistance? It's very easy to calculate: take trace geometry and copper resistivity, \$R = \rho L / (w h)\$. The power will be small.  Power may still be quite high relative to trace area and convection coefficient, but heat spreads out (somewhat poorly) through the board material, as well as (rapidly) along the trace(s). Heat flows with a similar rule (hence "thermal resistance"), and can be estimated from certain simple geometries if you like.

Comment: Ah yep. I was using a different calculator but Digikey has a nice one. So it should be fine to have 0.3mm wide and no need for tinning. Not sure why but I just didn't expect such a tiny trace to handle nearly 2A. Pretty impressive!